# Time difference in Excel

Tags: excel

I have two HH:MM values and I want to calculate the difference and show in floating format.

Like: (A1)14:00 (B1)17:30 (C1) X,X

X should be **3,5**

How should I write the formula? B1-A1 simply shows it as 3:30, which is not what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
=(B1-A1)*24
```

See this [link](http://www.excelfunctions.net/Convert-Time-To-Decimal.html).